Ubuntu 24.04 with dark stripe on screen display
I have recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my machine and sometimes I get a dark stripe on my screen, like a transparent bar. This is really annoying.
I am attaching a picture of it here for better understanding.
Has someone ever faced this issue?


Yes, this seems to be the case. I'll try the proposed solutions when it happens again and if it works I'll mark this question here as a duplicate. Thanks

At this point is a known bug in 24.04: the top answer did fix it for me, however yeah, I'd argue maybe you should try the solution now and if it doesn't happen again then you should accept the duplicate :D it's very sporadic, or at least it was for me

It is not a bug or a glitch. It is the OS showing you where a resized window will be tiled if you let go of the mouse button.

Unfortunately it is a bug/glitch since it doesn't go away after you let go of the mouse button.
